# Fetching row from Cassandra table with Spring

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

Hello am trying to fetch 10 rows of data from Cassandra table. But on each request same 10 row is returning. Please see my logic here. and advise me where am doing wrong here-

```
 public class CustomerRequestDaoImpl implements CustomerRequestDao
 {
  private static Cluster cluster;

 @Resource
  private CassandraSessionFactory cassandraSessionFactory;

   /** The ProductsByTagDaoImpl session. */
    private Session session;

  @Override
   public List<CustomerRequest> getCustomerRequestData(final String productId, final String receiptPeriod)
  {

   final int RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 10;

   session = cassandraSessionFactory.getSession();
   final List<CustomerRequest> customerRequestdata = new ArrayList<CustomerRequest>();
   try
   {
     final PreparedStatement statement =
      session.prepare("select * from customer_request where product_id = :id and receipt_period = :receiptPeriod");

     final BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);
     boundStatement.setFetchSize(RESULTS_PER_PAGE);
     boundStatement.setString("id", productId);
     boundStatement.setString("receiptPeriod", receiptPeriod);
     final ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(boundStatement);
     final Iterator<Row> iter = resultSet.iterator();
     final PagingState nextPage = resultSet.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();

     int remaining = resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching();
     for (final Row rowdt : resultSet)
     {
      customerRequestdata.add(constructCustomerReq(rowdt));
      if (--remaining == 0)
       {
         break;
       }
      }

    }
   catch (final Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return customerRequestdata;
  }

 @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    session = cassandraSessionFactory.getSession();
    cluster = session.getCluster();

  }
```

}

My Table-
       My Table structure:-

```
 CREATE TABLE customer_request (
  product_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
  id varchar,
  receipt_period varchar,
  delivery_method_status varchar,
  first_name varchar
  );
```

return Response-

```
  <e>
  <deliveryMethodStatus null="true"/>
  <firstName null="true"/>
  <id>0b0352f6b3904</id>
  <lastName Adkin="true"/>
  <orderId>FORMS8a04e</orderId>
  <orderItemId>FORMS8a04e-1</orderItemId>
  <productId>PI_NAME_CHANGE</productId>
  <receiptPeriod>2016-02-06</receiptPeriod>
  <receivedDate null="true"/>
  <requestData null="true"/>
```

Comment: Do you have a secondary index on column receipt_period ? Because if not, Cassandra do not allow you to query "where product_id = :id and receipt_period = :receiptPeriod"

Comment: o yes.. we do have secondary index on receipt_period

Comment: @doanduyhai- Sir any update?

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. My only doubt here is how to pass (String pagingState) for the 1st time request from UI side? When i pass as a null for the 1st time, I am getting error onsetting pagging state. boundStatement.setPagingState(PagingState.fromString(pagingState));

Comment: Add a null check on pagingState for first time query and don't inject it in boundStatement

Answer (score 0):

Several remarks:

- You **should not** re-prepare the query each time, it's an
  **anti-pattern**. Prepare the statement only once and re-use it for each method call
- The source code you show will **always return the first page of

  data** because you break out of the for loop once `remaining`
  variable counts down to 0. The `PagingState` object is not used
  anywhere ...
- You question is not clear either `Hello am trying to fetch 10 rows of
  data from Cassandra table. But on each request same 10 row is
  returning`. Which 10 rows do you want ? The **first** 10 rows ? The
  10 rows after a threshold ?

Sample code for paging:

Note: prepared the following query only **once**: `select * from customer_request where product_id = :id and receipt_period = :receiptPeriod LIMIT :lim` and pass it along with the method

```
 @Override
   public List<Tuple2<String,CustomerRequest>> getCustomerRequestData(final String productId, PreparedStatement ps, final String receiptPeriod, String pagingState)
  {

   final int PAGE_SIZE = 10;

   session = cassandraSessionFactory.getSession();
   final List<CustomerRequest> customerRequestdata = new ArrayList<CustomerRequest>();
   try
   {

     final BoundStatement boundStatement = ps.bind(productId, receiptPeriod, PAGE_SIZE);
     boundStatement.setPagingState(PagingState.fromString(pagingState));
     final ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(boundStatement);
     final Iterator<Row> iter = resultSet.iterator();
     final PagingState nextPage = resultSet.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();

     int remaining = resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching();
     for (final Row rowdt : resultSet)
     {
      customerRequestdata.add(constructCustomerReq(rowdt));
      if (--remaining == 0)
       {
         break;
       }
      }

    }
   catch (final Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return new Tuple2<>(nextPage.toString(), customerRe);
```

Please note the use of `Tuple2` class to return the list of results as well as the paging state, serialized as a String to be passed easily to the front-end

Comment: Hi I agree.. I am trying to get the subset of rows on each request. Like for 1st request want to retrieve 1-10 number of rows on second 11-20 rows, on 3rd request 21-30 rows. Can you please a bit explain on this scenario what i need to do? I am very much new to datastax . It would be very helpful if you edit the post and suggest. Thank you for replying Sir.

Comment: Do i need to pass start row and end row as param?

Comment: To help you, I will need the table structure. Can you post the CREATE TABLE script for this table please ?

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I have updated my post with table structure.